# Rails 4 link_to not generating correct resource path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a resource that I have set up to use :slug instead of :id in the url.

My `rake routes` looks like

```
     Prefix Verb URI Pattern              Controller#Action
       root GET /                        home#index
       home GET /                        home#index
course_type GET /courses/:slug(.:format) course_type#show
```

However, in my template(haml) when I do

```
= link_to course_type.name, course_type
```

It links to  `/courses/1` (`course_type` has `id:1` and `slug:"type_a"`). Shouldn't it point to `/courses/type_a`?

I also tried using `show_course_type_path` and `[:show, course_type]` but they both raised `undefined method: show_course_type_path`

How can I get rails to generate the correct path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your resource is CourseType and you have a @course_type instance variable:

```
link_to @course_type.name, course_type_path(@course_type.name)
```

This should out put something like:

```
<a href="/courses/course-name">course-name</a>
```

In order to use @course_type as the param, in course.rb:

```
def to_param
  name
end
```

Comment: This works, but is there any way to let rails know to do this automatically for link_to? It seems course_type_path(@course_type) is generating the path with id. Can I specify on the model/controller to use slug?

Comment: Yes there is! In your CourseType model, you need to override the 'to_param' method. [to_param](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param)

Comment: adding to_param fixes my initial link_to. Perfect!